# The network adapter could not establish the connection when switching between LAN and Public IP

Tags: oracle, webserver, weblogic

I have the following Database and Application Server setup in my test environment.

1.Parent Schema in different Server
2.Child schema in different server which accesses Views,Synonyms,tables from Parent Schema through DBLink.
3.Application Server (Weblogic)in different machine and created data source pointing to both Schema(Parent and Child).

Now fresh restart of all server from LAN access, everything works fine. Then i switch my test env to public ip(trough Web server), then any screen which looks for data in DB throws error i.e.The network adapter could not establish the connection. When i restart my Server from public ip, then everything works fine. Again switching to LAN, produces the same issue.

I have spent a week on this. Anyone if had faced this issue, please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can give more detail on exactly where you are setting and changing the addresses. Also are you using DNS/machine names, or explicit IP addresses? Including things you aren't changing; not sure if you're modifying JDBC entries etc., and if so whether you are resetting the connections afterwards. It's a bit vague at the moment. But, it's off-topic anyway really, I think.

Comment: Thanks..Alex...Yes i am using explicit IP addresses and i am not changing any JDBC entries also during switching.